# Make stacked barplot using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    condition       area
Month
Oct           Poor  11.386331
Oct          Better  65.483997
Oct     Favourable   5.165156
Oct    Exceptional  17.964516
Nov           Poor  14.589887
Nov          Better 62.965886
Nov     Favourable   4.942206
Nov    Exceptional  17.502020
Dec           Poor  29.718102
Dec          Better 52.317383
Dec     Favourable  10.754567
Dec    Exceptional   7.209948
```

I want to create a stacked bar plot, where for each month, each element of the stacked bar plot shows the corresponding area. However, when I do this:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=['orangered', 'yellow', 'limegreen', 'dodgerblue'])
```

I get:
[image]

Comment: Why the seaborn tag, if you're not actually using seaborn?

Comment: Also note that seaborn's creator strongly dislikes stacked bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is, that `df.plot.bar()` does not group the index of your Dataframe and stacks only multiply columns for the same index.

For your task you have to rearrange your data. For this use `reset_index` and [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot).

```
(df.reset_index()
 .pivot(index='Month', columns='condition', values='area')
 .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
)
```

[image: stacked bar plot]

If you print you DataFrame after `pivot()` it looks like this.

```
condition     Better  Exceptional  Favourable       Poor
Month     
Dec        52.317383     7.209948   10.754567  29.718102
Nov        62.965886    17.502020    4.942206  14.589887
Oct        65.483997    17.964516    5.165156  11.386331
```

Comment: thanks, is there  away to have the bar for Oct show up first, followd by Nov and then Dec?

Comment: `(df.reset_index().pivot(index='Month', columns='condition', values='area').reindex(['Oct','Nov','Dec']).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0))`